# SQL Server 2012 Data Integration

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

I'm writing an intranet application (in a LAMP environment) that uses data from sections of an MSSQL 2012 database (used by another much larger application).

As I see it my options are to:

- Directly query the database from the application.
- Create a web service
- Use Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services to have the data
  automatically integrated into my applications database

I'm sure the best solution here would be using SSIS, however I've not done this before am on a deadline - so if that's the case could someone let me know

a) With my limited experience in that area would I be able to set that up, and

b) What are the pros and cons of the above options?

Any other suggestions outside of the options I've thought of would also be appreciated

Comment: SSIS is one option but don't automatically assume it's the best option. It has it's own complications. Why can't your app read the db directly?

Comment: @ElectricLlama That is an option, I guess I'm looking for the pros and cons of that approach myself. Security is an obvious con. Updating my apps database from the server would be safer

Comment: You're the best one to answer your question, based on your knowledge of SSIS, the architecture of your applications, who supports the interface between the systems, what is appropriate as defined by your organization, etc etc. There are too many variables for us to give a good answer. I would say that in the past, I've ripped out many undocumented windows task scheduler interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options:

**Directly query the database from the application.**

Upside:

- Never any stale data

Downside:

- Your application now contains specific code and is tied that
  application
- If you are in the common situation where the business
  buys another application containing the same master data, you now
  need special code to connect to two applications
- Vendor might not like it
- Might be performance impacts on source application

**Use Windows Task Scheduler / SQL Agent to run a script or SSIS to replicate data at x minute intervals or so.**

Upside:

- Your application is only tied to your local copy of the database, which you can customise as required. If your source app gets moved to the cloud or something then you don't need to make application changes, just integration changes
- If another source application appears with the same type of master data, you can now replicate that into your local DB rather than making application changes to connect to 2 databases.

Downside:

- Possibility of stale data
- Even worse: possibility of stale data without users realising it, with subsequent loss of confidence in the application
- Another component to maintain

If you write a batch script, .Net app or SSIS, they are all pieces of logic that needs to be scheduled to run

Another option is to replicate the database using differential replication if your source database is Oracle or SQL, you can use replication to replicate it into another database.

You need to consider where you will be in a few years. The data copy method probably gives you more flexibility to adapt to changes in the source system as you only need to change your integration, not your whole app if something drastic changes with your source system.

You also need to consider: will you ever be asked to propogate changes back the other way, i.e. update data in your local copy and have it pushed back to the source systems.